Why are sections and subsections not appearing in the Table of Contents (TOC)?
I'm having trouble getting my sections and subsections to appear in the Table of Contents (TOC) of my LaTeX document. Here are some details about my setup:
Here is the main file:
% Overleaf has some problems with latexbangla packages : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575777/114006
% Download the project and compile it locally. I have complied it perfectly on Miktex latest version.
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !BIB program = biblatex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Includes up to subsubsections

\usepackage{bookstyle}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Needed for using fonts from local directory




\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\input{titlepage}

\mainmatter



    
\chapter{This is a Chapter }

% Section Example
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction.

% Subsection Example
\subsection{Background}









% article 1   ------------- edit its names as necessary 
\chapter[সূচিপত্রে ১ম নিবন্ধ শিরোনাম]{                                                                                % Short chapter title to show on the table of contents
\chapterphoto{example-image-golden}                                                                           % Chapter title photo or feature photo
১ম নিবন্ধের পূর্ণ শিরোনাম}                                                               
                              % Full chapter title to show on the chapter title page 
\chapterauthor{\href{https://github.com/rafisics/ebook-template}{১ম নিবন্ধের লেখক}}     % Chapter author name with url 
\newpage
\input{articles/article1}                                             
\chapterend

% article 2   ------------- edit its names as necessary 
\chapter[সূচিপত্রে ২য় নিবন্ধ শিরোনাম]{
\chapterphoto{example-image-golden} 
২য় নিবন্ধের পূর্ণ শিরোনাম}
\chapterauthor{\href{https://github.com/rafisics/ebook-template}{২য় নিবন্ধের লেখক}} 
\newpage
\input{articles/article2}
\chapterend


% More articles can be added here in the similar way
\backmatter
\input{endpage}

\end{document}

Output:

Here is the .sty file:
% !TEX root = main.tex
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Book Style
% --------------------------------------------------------------

% % space between line as percentage
\linespread{1.15}
% % space between paragraphs.
% \setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
% % paragraph indent
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}      % https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting#Paragraph_Indentation
% % discourage breaking of footnote text accorss multiple pages.
% \interfootnotelinepenalty=1000
% % to take care of nonbreakingspace issue in EU1 format of the .bbl
% \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }


% REQUIRED PACKAGES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% latexbangla with all features
\ifdefined\HCode
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
% \RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
%                 banglattfont=Kalpurush,
%                ]{latexbangla}
\else
\RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
                banglattfont=Kalpurush,
               ]{latexbangla}
%activate polyglossia
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\fi
%number all levels
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
    \setotherlanguage{english}

% \inlcudegraphics
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% % URL font is latex default Latin Modern Teletype. If you don't like that
% % change it to something else.
% \renewcommand\UrlFont{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}

% % autoref name for example env. when you call "In \autoref{blah}",
% % it will output "In udahoron blah"
% \newcommand\exampleautorefname{উদাহরণ}

% % translating autoref name for existing commands.
% \appto{\blockextras@bengali}{%
%   \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{সমীকরণ}%
% }
% % \appto{\blockextras@bengali}{%
% %   \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{নিবন্ধ}%
% % }
% \appto{\blockextras@bengali}{%
%   \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{সেকশন}%
% }
% \appto{\blockextras@bengali}{%
%   \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{চিত্র}%
% }


% title and section formatting
% \RequirePackage{titlesec}

% section sign before section number
% \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\raggedright\Large\bfseries}{{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\large§\,\uccon}\thesection}{0.5em}{}
% chapter sign before chapter number
% \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\raggedright\Large\bfseries}{{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\large§\,\uccon}\thechapter}{0.5em}{}

% % chapter title
% \RequirePackage{xcolor}
% \definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{60,60,60}
% \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%   {\bfseries\color{mygray}}
%   {\filleft%
%     \begin{tikzpicture}
%     \node[
%       outer sep=0pt,
%       text width=2.4cm,
%       minimum height=2.5cm,
%       fill=mygray,
%       font=\color{white}\fontsize{75}{80}\selectfont,
%       align=center
%       ] (num) {\thechapter};
%     \node[
%       rotate=90,
%       anchor=south,
%       font=\color{black}\Large
%       ] at ([xshift=-5pt]num.west) {\chaptertitlename};
%     \end{tikzpicture}%
%   }
%   {-30pt}
%   {\fontsize{22}{24}\selectfont}
%   % [\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt]
%   [{\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip-1em}]



% better double border intersection
% \RequirePackage{hhline}

% enlarged first letter
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\firstword}[2]{\lettrine[lines=3, lraise=0.2, nindent=0pt, findent=2pt]{#1}{#2}}




% table of contents formatting
\RequirePackage{tocloft}


% Set the depth of the ToC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Includes up to subsubsections

% Adjust dot leaders for chapters, sections, and subsections
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}    % For chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}     % For sections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}  % For subsections

% Customize the formatting of section and subsection titles in the ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}       % Normal font for section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}    % Normal font for subsection titles

% Customize the spacing and indentation
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{20pt}        % Indent sections under chapters
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{40pt}     % Indent subsections under sections
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{5pt}     % Space before each section in ToC
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{2pt}  % Space before each subsection in ToC


% \renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip-5pt}         % Decreasing the line spacing between the names of chapters

% % footnote in tables appear the end of page
% \RequirePackage{footnote}
% \makesavenoteenv{tabular}

% better float management
\RequirePackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/114006
% % multiple columns
% \RequirePackage{multicol}
% % compilation time decreases significantly with this package
% % although it produces a warning
% \RequirePackage{subfig}
% % breakable tables
\RequirePackage{longtable}

% NEW ENVIRONMENTS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% new font for quotation
\newfontfamily\quotefont[%
    Scale= 1.1,
    WordSpace=1.4,
    AutoFakeSlant=1.2,
    AutoFakeBold=1.2
    ]{[Monotype Corsiva]}
% \qtext command for english quote texts
\newcommand\qtext[1]{{\normalfont \uccoff \quotefont #1 \uccon}}

% % \chapquote command for quotes with author or source
% \RequirePackage{xparse}                % https://www.texdev.net/2010/05/23/from-newcommand-to-newdocumentcommand/
% \NewDocumentCommand\chapquote{mO{}O{}}{
%     \begin{quotation} 
%         \noindent  \itshape{#1}
%         \IfValueTF {#2}{
%             \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip} 
%             \begin{flushright} 
%                 \textemdash \quad \normalfont{#2} \par \footnotesize\itshape{#3}
%             \end{flushright}
%         }{}
%     \end{quotation} 
% }                              % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224069/114006

% \quote command for quotes with no author or source
\RenewDocumentCommand\quote{m}{
    \begin{quotation} 
        \noindent  \itshape{#1}
    \end{quotation} 
} 

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601754/114006
% \chapquote for quotes
\def\chapquote#1{%
   \begin{quotation} 
       \noindent  \itshape{#1}
   \futurelet\next\chapquoteA
}
\def\chapquoteA{\ifx\next[\expandafter\chapquoteB\else\expandafter\chapquoteC\fi}
\def\chapquoteB[#1][#2]{%
   \vskip.2\baselineskip
   \hfill \textemdash \quad 
   \ifx^#1^\else \normalfont #1\par \hfill \fi 
   \footnotesize\itshape #2\par
   \chapquoteC
}
\def\chapquoteC{\end{quotation}}


% % for customizable boxes
% \RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}


%% The below setup if From My preambles of main.tex file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{docmute}
\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
%\RequirePackage{physics}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{extarrows}
% \RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{blindtext}
\RequirePackage{mwe}
\RequirePackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}                     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56177/114006
\RequirePackage{cprotect}                    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8814/114006
\RequirePackage[numbered]{bookmark}          
\RequirePackage[font=footnotesize, justification=centering]{caption}
\RequirePackage[font=footnotesize, justification=centering]{subcaption}         % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119985/114006
% \setlist[itemize]{label*={\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\textbullet \uccon}}       % due to the Bangla fonts

\RequirePackage[
    papersize={5.5in, 8.5in}, 
    % margin=0.8in, 
    top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in, left=0.6in, right=0.6in, 
    headheight=15.04721pt
    ]{geometry}
\linespread{1.15}

%  % For a bilingual document
% \RequirePackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
%                 banglattfont=Kalpurush,
%                ]{latexbangla}
% %activate polyglossia
% \setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
% changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
% %number all levels
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%     \setotherlanguage{english}
%..............
\RequirePackage[autostyle]{csquotes}             % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39285/114006
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4506/114006
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, breaklinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta, 
    urlcolor=teal, 
}
\urlstyle{same}

% Adding header and footer on pages
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}                              % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\spaceskip=5pt\leftmark}   % Even pages (Left Header): Chapter Name
  \fancyhead[RO]{\spaceskip=5pt\rightmark}  % Odd pages (Right Header): Section Name
  \cfoot{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Adding References
% \RequirePackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, language=english, autolang=other]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{bookbib.bib}

% Adding pdf pages
\ifdefined\HCode%
\RequirePackage[dvips]{pdfpages}
\else
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\fi

%to allow long align env. to break between pages
\allowdisplaybreaks

% % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177179/114006        (need to improve)
% \tolerance=1
% \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
% \hyphenpenalty=10000
% \hbadness=10000

% Path relative to the main .tex file
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

% Adding footer on title page               https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199356/114006
\RequirePackage{titling}
% Shift up the title                  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29594/114006
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}       

%% Chapter title page style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Adding chapter sign and removing the vertical blank space before chapter heading     % https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284059/7673979
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
% {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
% {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{{\Huge\S\,}\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}        % Adding \S sign before on chapter number in English doc with default font
{\raggedright\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\Huge§\,\uccon}\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}     % % Adding \S sign before on chapter number in Bangla doc with latexbangla

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}     % this alters "before" spacing (the second length argument) to 0


% % Chapter sign before chapter number
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\@chapapp}{{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\Huge§\,\uccon}}
% \makeatother

% Adding Chapter Authors after chapter title:   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156865/114006
\RequirePackage{suffix}

\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\chapterauthor*[1]{\printchapterauthor{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\spaceskip=7pt\Large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.5em\mdseries\scshape\protect\spaceskip=4pt\footnotesize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-5pt}%
}
\makeatother

% Command for chapter title photo                    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91620/114006
\newcommand{\chapterphoto}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}\vspace{0.5cm}}

% Adding chapter ending symbol    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97175/114006
\RequirePackage{pgfornament}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\chapterend}{
    \par
    \vspace{\stretch{1}}
    \begin{center}
    \pgfornament[width=2.5cm]{84}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
}

% \newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}

% \newcommand{\chapterend}{
%     \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\measurepage>150pt}}{\chapterendsymbol}{}}

% Lists with special labels
\newcommand{\bulletlabel}{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\uccoff\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\textbullet\uccon}}
\newcounter{myitemizecounter}
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{list}{\bulletlabel\;\;}{\labelsep=0em \labelwidth=2em}}{\end{list}}

\newcommand{\diamondlabel}{\raisebox{2.5pt}{\includegraphics[height=8pt, angle=135]{listbullet01}}}
\newcounter{mylistcounter}
\newenvironment{mylist}
{\begin{list}{\diamondlabel\;\;}{\labelsep=0em \labelwidth=2em}}{\end{list}}

% Add dot to the end of chapter numbering in PDF bookmarks
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{#1. }            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150984/114006
\makeatother

% To avoid the problem of nameref and titlesec  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603305/114006
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcurrentname[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother

% Commnad for blank page texts         % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66901/114006
\newcommand*\bptext{পৃষ্ঠাটি ইচ্ছাকৃতভাবে খালি রাখা হয়েছে}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  % \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70718/114006
  \tiny\spaceskip=4pt\bptext
  % \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
  \vfill % equivalent to \vspace{\fill}
  % \thispagestyle{plain}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

Source file link: https://github.com/michal-h21/ebook-template
How can I add section and subsection in TOC?

! LaTeX Error: File \bookstyle.sty` not found.`

@cfr bookstyle.sty given above in hte last part

tidied erroneous comments ... but you don't need all those packages to show the problem and you still have e.g. \input{titlepage}.

note that you currently set the toc depth to 3 which will include subsubsections, too, if I'm not confused again. but you have a lot of code - not always consistent - after. and you are loading packages which are likely to conflict, loading them multiple times and loading them in the wrong order. so whether 3 survives the chaos is another question.

off-topic: you don't need \makeatletter in a .sty. @ is already a letter there and you don't generally use \makeatother because it should stay a letter unless you have special reason to change that temporarily in a controlled way.

Latex source  files : https://github.com/michal-h21/ebook-template

unless you are extraordinarily lucky, nobody is going to comb through reams of code to find the problem. questions should be self-contained so they remain useful to future readers. please edit your question to provide a complete but minimal example we can compile to reproduce the problem.

strong recommendation: do not use the files from that repo. that the chaos I mentioned above is not of your making will not stop the consequences wreaking havoc on your project. the code will cause you trouble in spades. don't use it.

Your code cannot be compiled by anybody but you since it uses \input for files we do not have.
The following minimal example, demonstrates that setting tocdepth to 2 causes sections and subsections to be included in the table of contents.
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Title
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{c}
\section{s}
\subsection{ss}
\chapter{C}
\section{S}
\subsection{Ss}
\subsubsection{Sss}
\backmatter
PS
\end{document}


